# TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Hero>'

Tags: typescript, angular

Here hero.service.ts constructor

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  private _heroObserver: Observer<Hero>;
  hero$:   Observable<Hero>; 
  public errorMessage: string;

  constructor (private http: Http) {
    this.hero$   = new Observable((observer:any) =>  this._heroObserver = observer).share();  // line 29
  }
```

It compiles with error

```
[0] hero.service.ts(29,9): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is
not assignable to type 'Observable<Hero>'.
[0]   Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Hero'.
[0]     Property '_id' is missing in type '{}'.
```

What is Type '{}' referred to and how to fix it?

PS: this is on beta-16.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? Looks like a very weird piece of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
this.hero$   = new Observable<Hero>((observer:any) =>  this._heroObserver = observer).share();  // line 29
```

Comment: thank you. Now I understand where the type {} is coming from. Works perfect.